# How to get typescript for electron.js file when using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

In all the articles that explain how to use create-react-app with electron (eg : https://www.codementor.io/randyfindley/how-to-build-an-electron-app-using-create-react-app-and-electron-builder-ss1k0sfer ) , they mention that electron.js file should be placed within `public` folder.

I want to have typescript definitions for this electron.js too (since i am using typescript for the react app also). How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have spent quite a bit of time working on an electron project as well as creating a starter kit for using Electron + TypeScript (very strict) + Create React App (non-ejected). I think you might find it useful as a starting point, even though there might be some additional tooling that you might not need.

Check out the [electron branch of Foldable](https://github.com/jamesstoneco/foldable/tree/electron) for more details. Of particular interest would be [src/electron.ts](https://github.com/jamesstoneco/foldable/blob/electron/src/electron.ts), [package.json](https://github.com/jamesstoneco/foldable/blob/electron/package.json) and the public dir.

To quickly give you some additional points that might be useful in your question:

1. One can configure the entry script for Electron in your `package.json` under "main"
2. You will need to use TSC or another typescript compiler to handle the "main-thread" or node portion of Electron. This is separate from CRA. Alternatively you can use plain javascript for a simpler setup.
3. The only thing in my public folder is the html file minus the javascript imports (because they are injected automatically)